# Getting started with SOAP

Tags: web-services

A site I developed has a new requirement to get weather data from the National Weather Service. They have quite a bit of info on how to use SOAP to get their data and display it in the browser, but what we need to do is use a cron job to get the data at specific intervals, then parse the data out into a database.

I have no problem writing PHP code that will run an XSLt and parse xml records out into SQL queries, but I have no idea how to handle this with SOAP (which I've never worked with.) Do I get the data via a SOAP request, save it to an XML file on my web server, then run the XSLt against that? Or is there some other way to go about this?

Comment: Do you have to use PHP? Got any other choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the web service call, the HTTP response payload will contain a SOAP envelope encapsulating the application response.
Basically the whole HTTP response is XML, the SOAP part and the application data.

```
<soap>
     <header></header><!--Optional-->
     <body>
        <applicationData>
        </applicationData>
     </body>
</soap>
```

So you only need get the child of `body` to have the xml fragment that encapsulates the application data for your service and work on this.
There can be only 1 child element of `body` per WS-Profile BP specification.
Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am not a PHP expert, but the following is a simple tutorial for writing Soap Servers and Clients in PHP.  I guess you will run the PHP script using the command line interface.

http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2007/07/26/php-web-services.html?page=2

But if you are running a cron job, other languages may be better. PHP's soap support is not well documented.